# AppEngine and JDO: fetch objects in unowned relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

Unowned one-to-many and many-to-many relationships are defined using Sets or Lists of Keys. Let's say I have an object of an article containing set of keys of labels of the article. So how do I fetch the labels themselves? The objects matching the keys? How do I iterate over them? Naturally I could iterate over the keys and fetch the objects separately, but is this the only way? I tried to find the answer everywhere but I wasn't successful. The documentation describes defining unowned relationships in detail, but is silent about making queries on them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you have what Google was originally calling an "unowned relation" ? (where you have a `Set<Key>`). Sadly that is not a **relation** at all IMHO, since there is no related object involved. With v2.x of their plugin you can have a [real unowned relation](http://datanucleus.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/gaej-and-datanucleus-v3-part-2.html) (the example there is for 1-1, but you can equally have `Set<B>`) where everything looks as it should. I'd strongly advise you to use that (the keys are stored in the parent, so a single call is made to get the Set of related objects).

Comment: So in v2.x the keys are stored in the parent using Set<B> for both owned and unowned relationships and I turn unowned into owned by adding "parent" attribute to the child object and "mappedBy" annotation to the parent object? Querying is the same in both cases? You recommend me to use the v2.x version of the plugin which is currently marked as experimental, you think that there is nothing to worry about? And I'm still a little bit confused why this technique of creating unowned relationship (Set<Key>) is described in the documentation when it is actually useless...

Comment: GAE JPA v2 (written by me) passes way more tests than their v1 ever did, follows TDD and has stability implicit in its development (Google insist on labelling things as experimental and such like - best ask them why). The only complication is where you have existing data ... since the data storage format changed when dev of v2 was started (so you'd have to migrate any data from v1 - see the Wiki of their plugin). The old GAE way of "unowned" should store the keys in the parent too AFAIK (not that I used it), just the new way gives you immediate access to your related objects.

Comment: This is quite old and closed... but I have a follow up problem. I upgraded to v2 plugin and tried to implement unowned relationship using the convenient natural syntax but here is the thing... removing the reference also deletes the original object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844175/jdo-in-appengine-keep-the-original-entity-when-deleting-from-unowned-relationsh for more information. So at this moment I have to implement relationships using Keys. You seemed like well informed guy... any ideas?

Comment: I think someone advised you to report issues in the GAE JDO/JPA issue tracker if you're having problems, so they can look at it ... with a testcase that demonstrates it. His advice ought to be followed IMHO

Comment: Well I did that but no response so far. I am apparently the only one having this problem. On the other hand, I haven't met anyone who said this worked for him. So maybe nobody uses JDO3 for implementing relationships. Never mind, thank you anyway. For now I'll use Keys for implementing relationships, it's workinng fine and there is not much extra work.

Comment: You did that? Where? It's not in their issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/list

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I posted it to the general issue tracker list. I'll fix it when I get to my pc.

Comment: So here it is: http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=290&thanks=290&ts=1344966091