# JDO in AppEngine: keep the original entity when deleting from unowned relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have defined an unowned relationship using JDO 3.0 syntax:

```
@Persistent
@Unowned
private Set<Role> roles;
```

I have several predefined roles which should be assigned to users. I use following code for adding/removing roles to users:

```
roles.add(roleEntity);
roles.remove(roleEntity);
```

The problem is that removing like this also removes the original entity from the datastore but I just want to remove the reference. I know I could store only Keys inside the parent entity which would solve the problem, but is there a better solution? Using this "natural" syntax?

Comment: AFAIK, unowned relationships are never dependent, so this should not happen. OTOH this could happen IF your `Role` is serialized (`@Persistent(serialized=true)`) or embedded (`@Embedded`).

Comment: The Role is neither serialized nor embedded. This is the code of the Role entity http://pastebin.com/ZRLNhiWm ...nothing special.

Comment: an unowned relation can be dependent or not dependent based on standard cascade delete settings ... for GAE or for any datastore ... and obviously there is an incomplete definition of any problem

Comment: Well, that's good to know. I tried simple dependent="false", but it didn't work. I also tried to google the problem, but unsuccessfully... What should I do disable this cascade deleting?

Comment: @NeilStockton: am I missing something? Docs say that only owned relationships can be dependent: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Dependent_Children_and_Cascading_Deletes

Comment: That's the problem! In my case, unowned relationships behave like dependent. I don't know how is that possible. The only exception is when I call roles.clear(), the references are deleted but original objects stay in datastore. But when I go through roles using loop and for each I call roles.remove(role), it deletes the original entities from the datastore as well.

Comment: @PeterKnego I refer to the JDO spec and standards handling, not some Google doc. If a collection is marked as having dependent elements then they are deleted if removing one from the collection. I find Google's docs to be way out of date

Comment: @Neil Stockton The collection is _not_ marked as dependent in my case. You mentioned "standard cascade delete settings" in your first post, where do I find them? Could you post here the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: The "documentation" is the JDO spec, publically available, and recommended reading for anyone using JDO. I think the DataNucleus docs cover such things well enough too. Google docs not so. If you have this not being followed then you ought to raise an issue in GAE JDO issue tracker showing them a testcase ... but unowned relations are new there so who knows if its complete

Comment: Well, the documentation (found on datanucleus.org) says among other things: _If the element is dependent then it will be deleted when removed from the collection. The same happens when the collections is cleared._ In my case, clearing collection does nothing. The entities disappear from the datastore only when they are removed using .remove() from the collection (see my comment above). So the relation is neither dependent nor not-dependent. It's something in between. Is it a bug? I was hoping for some more specific ideas and suggestions when I posted this question...

Comment: Little update: something is really broken in appengine. I made some experiments and for both, owned and unowned relationship, depedent="false/true" has no effect, no matter what I do, the relationship is always dependent. The only exception is when I call .clear() on the collection. For owned relationships it deletes the original entities as well, for unowned relationships it doesn't.

Comment: hey tobik you are right! i have the same probleme... i saw you created an official issue and it is solved. where can i download a new .jar? or is there a workaround in the old version?

Comment: I switched back to JDO 2.0 and I implement unowned relationships using collections of keys or foreign keys. I'm sorry but I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this question deserves a real final answer.

The described behavior was caused by a bug in JDO and it should be fixed by now. See http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=290 for more details. Also notice, that `owned` relationships are *always* `dependent`, no matter what the documentation says.

Unfortunately, it was fixed after I had moved back to **JDO 2.0**. In JDO 2.0, I implement `unowned` relationships using `collections of keys` or using `foreign keys`. And actually it's not a bad solution so I don't plan to try **JDO 3.0** again. For a collection of keys I use `batch fetch` to get child objects, in case of foreign keys, I use simple queries with `where` statement. Sometimes it's better to use the first solution, sometimes the second one. It's all covered by a clean API anyway, so the final code is simple and "natural". (I wish this approach was described directly in the documentation so we don't have to learn it the hard way.)

The important thing is that in both cases I can destroy the relationship without deleting original entities. It's a true `unowned` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing.  Granted I'm a newbie to all this, but even with @Unowned
if I remove an item from an ArrayList which it was on when first persisted the
object is deleted from the data store. Seems pretty much the same as before I added
@Unowned. So the only way I can transfer the object from the ArrayList of one object
to that of another is to find it first before calling remove(), then make a deep copy,
then I can remove() and put the copy on the other list.  Not at all natural.

Answer (score 1):

As I've struggled with this for ages, let me share the solution that finaly works for me. Who knows, it might help someone else as the documentations are not very helpful.

To remove a child from the parent's collection without deleting the original persitent object you need to:

1) Use a **Set** not a List

At first I used only Lists, A) for the ordering and B) because Sets + RequestFactory ValueProxy doesn't work. So be sure to use **EntityProxy**

2) Anotate this set with **@Unowned**

They didn't put this annotation in their Unowned one-to-many example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Unowned_Relationships
But without it you get an exception when you try to add an element to your set (can't change parent)

3) Not sure it's necessary but I've also annotated with **@Element(dependent = "false")**

Hope this will help some people. If not, well, no harm done.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't imagine it would make any difference if I used List or Set, but it actually did. Thanks to you I solved my issue where updating a parent-entity caused duplicate entries because it thought the child-entitites didn't exist, even though they did.

It's weird Google Docs doesn't mention that Set is kind of a MUST in some situations. And the missing @Unowned bothered me, because I wasn't sure i needed it! Also do you happend to know if SortedSet works as well?

Thanks again!

Comment: Hello there,
You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help. :)
Concerning the SortedSet, haven't tried it in a unowned relationship. My guess is that it should work, as long as of course you provide a comparator, but you never know. Testing it shouldn't take long though.